# Devise not handling url fragments correctly on authentication and stored_location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

When not authenticated navigating to a URL with a fragment i.e. `http://localhost/account/linguists/11367#references` causes a redirect to the sign in url with the same fragment i.e. `http://localhost/users/sign_in#references`.

Then when using the stored_location to redirect the fragment is not used

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with the same problem, it is fixed since v3.5.0 of devise gem. See issue here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/pull/3295

Comment: I tried upgrading to 3.5.10 but it didn't seem to work for me